# Rename Realm table

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a `Gift` table in my realm scheme. Now I need to rename `Gift.class` to `UserBonus.class` and add some new params(not a prob). What is the correct way to do this?

I know that `realm.getTable()` can return me the table, the problem is that old `Gift`exists in the schema but on fact I dont have `Gift.class`(now it is `UserBonus` and `getTable()` will return me new created table) so I cant get old gift table values and move them to new Bonus table.

The only way I see it, to left empty `Gift.class` and use it only for migration.

Thanks for any advice,
Yakiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I did implement it as follow:

- added new `UserBonus.class`
- added @Deprecated to `Gift.class`
- copy all data from `Gift` table to `UserBonus` table

  ```
  // added bonus types
  Table userBonus = realm.getTable(UserBonus.class);
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "localId");
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.INTEGER, "type");
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.INTEGER, "date");
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "userName");
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "userNumber");
  userBonus.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "credits");

  // move Gift to UserBonus
  RealmResults<Gift> gifts = realm.where(Gift.class).findAll();
  for (Gift gift :gifts) {
      userBonus.add(
              gift.getLocalId(),
              UserBonus.TYPE_FRIEND,
              gift.getDate(),
              gift.getUserName(),
              gift.getUserNumber(),
              gift.getCredits()
      );
  }
  realm.where(Gift.class).findAll().clear();
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe my answer will be outdated, but now in Realm on Android there is a method 'rename', which can rename table (model) in scheme.
Code will be like this:

```
RealmSchema schema = Realm.getInstance().getSchema();
schema.rename("OldModelName", "NewModelName");
```

And it should work!

Also you can see all features in Migration (from 25 Jun 2015) - https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1239